# Riemann-integral of a non-continuous function

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f : \,\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function with a discontinuity at point $x_0$. How can I prove *formally* that $f$ the Riemann-integral of $f$ exists, i.e. that $f$ fulfills

$\sum_k (\sup f(I_k)-\inf f(I_k)) \lvert I_k\rvert \lt \varepsilon$ for a proper partition.

My idea: Let $x_0 \in [a,b] $ Now I choose $\delta$ so that $[x_0-\delta, x_0 + \delta] \subset [a,b] $ .

Now I can divide $[a,b] = [a,x_0-\delta] \cup [x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta] \cup [x_0+\delta, b]$. Since $f$ is continuos on $[a,x_0-\delta]$ and  $[x_0+\delta, b]$, applying this method over and over again makes the difference of upper sum and lower sum arbitrary small.

But how do I formulate this last step mathematically correct?

Comment: Just mentioning that this is not in general true if $f$ has an infinite discontinuity at $x_0$.

Comment: As @Eoin says, the problem is misstated. Would be nice if you restated it with the correct hypotheses.

Comment: Okay, $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. Given $\epsilon>0$, first you need to choose $\delta$ small enough to control the difference between the lower and upper sums on $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. Since there's a discontinuity there, you can't try to exploit continuity, so instead, just use the fact that $f$ is bounded: let $M=\sup f - \inf f$ and choose $\delta<\epsilon/3M$. Then the difference between the lower and upper sums on $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ is at most $\epsilon/3$.

Finally, choose partitions of $[a,x_0-\delta]$ and $[x_0+\delta,b]$ fine enough that each of them have a difference of at most $\epsilon/3$ (this can be done because of continuity). Adding up the differences, they can't be any larger than $\epsilon$.

Note that I've implicitly assumed that $f$ is bounded. This assumption is necessary: for example, your result fails if $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ and $1/(x-1)$ on $(1,2]$, even though this function is only discontinuous at $1$.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is bounded. Could you explain how you conclude that $\delta \lt \epsilon / 3m $ implies that the difference between the lower and upper sums is at most $\epsilon / 3$ ?

Comment: @Christian I actually made a small arithmetic error; I should have said $\delta<\epsilon/6M$. For then the upper sum is at least $\sup f \cdot 2\delta$ while the lower sum is at most $\inf f \cdot 2 \delta$ so the difference is at most $(\sup f - \inf f) 2 \delta < 2M \epsilon/6M = \epsilon/3$.

Comment: I have to admit I still don't get it. 
I would say $(\sup f - \inf f) vol([x_0-\delta , x_0+\delta]) \lt \epsilon $ , so $M2\delta \lt \epsilon$ or $\delta \lt \epsilon/2M $

Comment: @Christian I choose a slightly smaller $\delta$ so that the difference between the upper and lower sums *for the entire partition* is less than $\epsilon$. But this is a question of style; you can make the pieces be less than $\epsilon$, add them up and get $3 \epsilon$. If $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small then so is $3 \epsilon$; one can phrase this in different ways. The style I used happens to be more common in the literature (because it is more "beginning-to-end", I guess).